# AutoMapper.Collection.EFCore - Error thrown during Configuration

Tags: automapper, automapper-collections-ef-core

AutoMapper.Collection.EFCore was just published today on Nuget, and I am now trying to use.

I have set it up according to the [Docs:](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection.EFCore/blob/master/README.md)

In startup.cs, in the ConfigureServices method:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.AddCollectionMappers();
    cfg.SetGeneratePropertyMaps<GenerateEntityFrameworkCorePrimaryKeyPropertyMaps<ApplicationDbContext>>();
});
```

This exception is thrown:

`InvalidOperationException: Use AddEntityFrameworkCoreKeys instead of using SetGeneratePropertyMaps.`

However, I do not find any such method on `cfg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renamed to UseEntityFrameworkCoreModel. You should report it so they change the message.

Comment: I have submitted issue to fix.

Comment: What is the full syntax I should be using?  `cfg.UseEntityFrameworkCoreModel<DbContext>(services);` throws an exception of `'No service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' has been registered.'
`

Comment: I have no idea, but I would guess it's your job to register the DbContext. Check the tests in the repo.